# ngdialog - close the parent dialog when opening the child dialog

Tags: angularjs, ng-dialog

I have a scenario like below graph:
[image]

I need to close the parent dialog when i just open the child dialog, how can i achieve that?

I tried like using closing API just before opening the child dialog, the parent dialog is closed, but all the data needed in the child dialog will be undefined. If i do not close it, the data in child dialog can be displayed well.

```
$scope.selectServerToOpen = function (serverType) {
    var newScope = $scope.$new(true);
    newScope.newServer = $scope.newServer;
    $scope.closeThisDialog('cancel');//coment this line, the data can be passed correctly, but i need to close the parent dialog when i open the child dialog
    modalInstance = ngDialog.open
                template: 'servers/templates/servers-new.tpl.html',
                scope: newScope,
                controller: 'newServerCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    serverData: function () {
                        return null;
                    },
                    delegate: callbackWrapper
                }
            });
```

Comment: It's because controller is getting initialized again

Comment: @Sajeetharan Thanks for your answer, do you have any work around for this?

Answer (score -1):

You can check here, its will show exactly what you want : https://www.dmgint.de/auswertung/libs/angularjs/ngDialog/example/index.html